# Pass in pointer of c struct to x86-32 assembly becomes automatically dereference

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, struct

I need to pass an address to an assembly function, but seems like I'm not able to do that.

Here's the c file:

```
int asm_func(void *arg);

struct foo {
int len;
   char *buf;
};

int bar(int size, char *buf){
   struct foo arg_to_asm_function;
   arg_to_asm_function.len = size;
   arg_to_asm_function.buf = buf;
   return asm_func(&arg_to_asm_function);
}
```

Here's the assembly:

```
.global asm_func

asm_func:
   pushl    %esi
   movl     8(%ebp), %esi

   /* do something with &arg_to_asm_function, which is in esi */

   popl     %esi
   ret
```

If I invoke the c function bar with arguments bar(5, "hello world"), and I stepi into the instruction

```
movl 8(%ebp), %esi
```

I get the value 5 in %esi (value of first field in the struct foo).

The expected value in %esi is the pointer to the struct foo that I declared, i.e. &arg_to_asm_function, not the value inside that address.

Why is this happening? Does the compiler automatically dereference the pointer for me? How would I pass in the address of the struct into %esi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't set up the stack frame in the assembly function, so `8(%ebp)` won't give you the correct value. Because `ebp` still has the value from your C function, you're seeing the value of the first argument passed to that function instead.

You need to set up the stack frame with

```
push %ebp
mov %esp, %ebp

...

pop %ebp
```

This is assuming that the calling convention passes the function parameters on the stack - otherwise you'll need to get the parameter value from a register.

Comment: I would up vote your answer If I had more than 15 reputation. big thanks though.